# How can I configure upload a few files sequentially to AWS S3 via the AWS web UI (aka "AWS Management Console")?

Tags: upload, amazon-web-services

I upload a few files to S3 via the AWS web UI (aka "AWS Management Console"):

[image]

By default, as shown on the screenshot, it uploads all files simultaneously.

How can I configure upload a few files sequentially to AWS S3 via the AWS web UI? E.g., in the screenshot, I want file `c.zip` to be done uploading before `d.zip` starts to get uploaded.